# prestashop check cookie is set from the module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I am developing a module in Prestashop 1.6.X . In this module I am setting a custom cookie using js.

Now in the module php file I am  checking if the cookie is set then do something. So for that I am doing this code

```
if (isset( $_COOKIE['mycookie'] )) { 
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Here mycookie is the cookie name that I have made set using js

Its working fine. But when I am trying to validate the module its showing error. It is showing error like

`The use of $_COOKIE is forbidden; use Context::getContext()->cookie`

instead. So can someone tell me how to check the cookie name by using Context::getContext()->cookie.

I have tried 
`Context::getContext()->cookie('mycookie')`
 But its not working. 
Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: did you solved this problem? im also facing the same

Comment: this validation can be passed by putting this type of forbidden code in seperate php files in non prestashop folders (create folder like helper or lib or other than classes, controllers etc..) and include it in the module. So prestashop validator assumes, the file is an external / 3rd party library and skips its validation

Comment: The technique for any folder except classes or controllers is not working in prestashop 1.7.X.
@AbdullaChozhimadathil 
Can you please suggest me an alternative for that?

Answer (score -2):

```
if(isset(Context::getContext()->cookie->mycookie)){
    //your code
}
```